# Installshield: Allow installing setup only if another setup is installed

Tags: installshield

I have 2 setups: setup A, setup B. 
Setup B is dependent on setup A.
Meaning, only if setup A is installed, setup B can be install, otherwise, a relevant message will pop up.

How can I create such dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom prerequisite.

Most prerequisites just look for a registry entry. If Setup A has a constant registry entry you can set that as a prerequisite.

https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetPrereqCustom.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, with the native MSI support for Launch Conditions. 
https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpProdCondition.htm

All known packaging tools have this support, most of them also give you the options to extend it with custom conditions.